# Prolog Numbers to Words

Tags: string, recursion, prolog, integer, words

I am working with the following predicates to convert numbers to words:

```html
word(0) :- write('zero').
word(1) :- write('one').
word(2) :- write('two').
word(3) :- write('three').
word(4) :- write('four').
word(5) :- write('five').
word(6) :- write('six').
word(7) :- write('seven').
word(8) :- write('eight').
word(9) :- write('nine').
dash(X) :- 
    write('-'). %need to add some code here to not print dash after last dig
    

num_words(Nums) :- 
    Nums > 0,
    NMod is Nums mod 10,
    NDiv is Nums // 10,     
    word(NMod),
    dash(Nums), 
    num_words(NDiv).
```

**Desired Output:**

```
num_words(123) => one-two-three
```

**Current Output:**

```
num_words(123) => three-two-one-
```

Looking at my output, it looks like my logic is almost correct, but I am failing to grasp how to change the recursion to print the numbers "backwards" so that they are in the right order and how to alter my `dash(x)` predicate to not print a dash after the last digit.

Do you guys have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to solving issues where the first or the last action must be different from the rest of the actions is to split your predicate in two. In this situation, you can make your top-level predicate that calls `word(digit)`, and then calls another predicate that prints the "tail" of your number, always adding a dash after the digit.

In addition, you need to re-arrange the recursion in such a way that the digits computed later be printed earlier.

```
num_words(Nums) :-       % This is top-level predicate.
    NDiv is Nums // 10,  % It prints the first digit unconditionally,
    dash_num_words(NDiv),% letting you handle the case when the number is zero.
    NMod is Nums mod 10, 
    word(NMod).

dash_num_words(0).       % When we reach zero, we stop printing.

dash_num_words(Nums) :-  % Otherwise, we follow your algorithm
    Nums > 0,            % with one modification: the dash is printed
    NDiv is Nums // 10,  % unconditionally before printing the digit.
    dash_num_words(NDiv),
    NMod is Nums mod 10,
    word(NMod),
    write('-').
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/zMcUEQ)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense for fixing the dash issue. Is there a way I can reorder my calls to my predicates to print the numbers in the correct order, or should I just alter my algorithm?

Comment: @DomnWerner You are right, I missed the digit flipping. I re-arranged the code, and added some explanation of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Using this post: [Split a number into a list of digits in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701991/split-a-number-into-a-list-of-digits-in-prolog) you will only need to use a recursive predicate to print the resulting list.

```
word('0') :- write('zero').
word('1') :- write('one').
word('2') :- write('two').
word('3') :- write('three').
word('4') :- write('four').
word('5') :- write('five').
word('6') :- write('six').
word('7') :- write('seven').
word('8') :- write('eight').
word('9') :- write('nine').

num_words(X):- number_chars(X,C), printout(C).

printout([N]):- word(N),!.
printout([N|Tail]):- word(N),write('-'),printout(Tail).
```

Consult:

```
?- num_words(1234567890).
 one-two-three-four-five-six-seven-eight-nine-zero
true.
```

I also change the facts word enclosing the number in quotes. If you don't like that, we can change it.

Comment: You could also avoid changing the OP's facts by using `atom_number/2` before `word(N)` in your `printout/1` predicate clauses.

Answer (score 0):

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23311935/874024), for a more general viewpoint about numeric literals. From the source:

```
% Grammar for numbers, e.g.
% phrase(number(I),[two,hundred,and,fifty,six]).
% An astonishing characteristic of this code is that it's
% fully bidirectional. The expression
% phrase(number(256),Words)
% will instantiate Words = [two,hundred,and,fifty,six].
% What's more,
% phrase(number(I),Words)
% will eventually instantiate I and Words to all the numbers it knows.
%
% Ken Johnson 17-9-87
```